# Dropdown updates another dropdown with jquery and sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, updates

How can I update another dropdown with jquery with sql.
It means from database.

```
  $('#typeOfGlass').on('change', function(){
   console.log($('#typeOfGlass').val());
    $('#glassWidth').html('');
    if($('#typeOfGlass').val()==15){
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="19">19</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="20">20</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="21">21</option>');
    }else{
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="6">6</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="7">7</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="8">8</option>');
        $('#glassWidth').append('<option value="9">9</option>');
    }
});
```

I use this one but i dont have idea how to make it from database.

```
$sqlq="SELECT DISTINCT daerah FROM kampung WHERE negeri='$negeri'";
    $result_set=mysqli_query($conn, $sqlq);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value=".$row['daerah'].">".$row['daerah']."</option>";
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can use AJAX to achieve this, however your question is far too broad to be answered effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to change the query or add info to your table so the program has a way to find out whether or not to append a specific `<option>` to the `<select>`.

Next, fetch all rows into an array. This should work, but I didn't test it:

```
$rows = array();
while ($rows[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Now pass this data to JavaScript:

```
echo "<script> var data = " . json_encode($rows) . "; </script>";
```

Finally, when `#typeOfGlass` is changed, clear `#glassWidth`, then iterate over `data` and append only the relevant elements, depending on `#typeOfGlass`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

An option to achive this may be using Ajax as @Rory McCrossan suggested. The process is quiet long for a precise anwser but I will give you a few step you are going to need to do.

If you have your query working in your php and your html is working fine too, you just need to glue them together. So you can use javascript to do that. This is a expmaple of a Ajax query

```
    $.ajax({
                url: www.yoursite.com, //file you made to process the request
                type: "GET", // or POST 
                success: function(data) { 
                    if (data.success === 'ok'){
                      // code of what to do if the call returns ok
                      // probably update your options
                    }
                },
                error: function(exeption){
                   var response = jQuery.parseJSON(exeption.responseText);
                   alert(response.error);
// what to do if the process fail
                }
```

So use php to make to process the query and return you new options. If you get stock on a more especific part let us know. Good luck